# Cannot connect to each button of alert and action sheet in Xcode 5 and Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

First, in the following header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
- (IBAction)btnSheet1:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

-(void) actinSheet:(UIActionSheet *) actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
@end
```

And the implementation file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)btnSheet1:(id)sender 
{
    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Do it!" otherButtonTitles:@"other button", nil];
    sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void) actinSheet:(UIActionSheet *) actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button: %d pressed", buttonIndex];
    } 
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button: %d pressed", buttonIndex];
    }
}


@end
```

When I ran my simulator, the button and label were successfully shown up on the screen. However, when I clicked on the button to have the action sheet popped up, and then tried to press one of the buttons in order to make `myLabel` changed to other strings, the label didn't change...

I also tried to do the same thing on alert view, but it didn't work too.

So why does the code not work? The entire snippets are from [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009UA6YV0) and that book assumes to use iOS 6 and Xcode 4, but I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5, which may be a culprit?

For your information, I connected the label to `IBOutlet`, and the button to `IBAction`, which is what the aforementioned book does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work, you are writing the delegate wrong:

```
-(void) actinSheet:(UIActionSheet *) actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

It should be **`actionSheet`**.

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *) actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: Oops. Xcode is such a terrific tool that I owed all of my typos to its automatic correction, that I didn't check out even user-defined properties and methods. Thanks and sorry...